# Do I need profiles for tests in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I have application on spring-boot with any profiles for different servers(qa, dev, etc.)So, this is application.properties with different params.

Do I need addition application.properties for every server in test/resources for every servers or I need to use only src/resouces profiles?

Answer (score 0):

You would want one application.properties that holds default values and then override properties files for each profile.